# Set up selenium webdriver with ruby(i have ruby mines), cucumber and capybara in windows 7

Tags: selenium

I want to setup selenium webdriver with ruby cucumber and capybara in window 7 to practice at home. Can some one provide detail steps.

Answer (score 0):

selenium comes by default with capybara, add :js => true to your cucumber steps and you should be good to go.  I am using rspec without cucumber but i have something like

```
describe "Something" do 
it "should use selenium", js: true do 

page.should have_content "It works!"
end
```

you should see firefox come up
you may wanna consider a headless driver to cut down on the browser startup cost

Here's a project from Rails 3 in Action that has some features  using selenium

https://github.com/rails3book/ticketee

Answer (score 0):

I put an example:

```
require "selenium-webdriver"
gem "test-unit"
require "test/unit"

class Papidal < Test::Unit::TestCase

  def setup
    @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
    #@base_url = "http://localhost:8090/"
    @accept_next_alert = true
    @driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 30
    @verification_errors = []
  end

  def teardown
    @driver.quit
    assert_equal [], @verification_errors
  end

  def test_papidal
    @driver.get("http://localhost:8090/myproject/")
    @driver.find_element(:xpath, "//a[@wicketpath='showModalLink']").click
  end

  def element_present?(how, what)
    @driver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end

  def verify(&blk)
    yield
  rescue Test::Unit::AssertionFailedError => ex
    @verification_errors << ex
  end

  def close_alert_and_get_its_text(how, what)
    alert = @driver.switch_to().alert()
    if (@accept_next_alert) then
      alert.accept()
    else
      alert.dismiss()
    end
    alert.text
  ensure
    @accept_next_alert = true
  end
end
```

If you want use this with Internet Explorer:

- Change @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox by this @driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :ie
- Put in your PATH (environment variables): IEDriverServer.exe (you can download this from: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/downloads/detail?name=IEDriverServer_x64_2.30.2.zip) and execute this before execute the script